# Does anyone know what this green/yellow/red houseplant is?

Tags: houseplants

I bought it at the farmer's market and the vendor did not seem to know what it was. It's driving me crazy! :-)[image]

Answer (score 3):

Judging by its fleshy leaves, I think it's Peperomia clusiifolia Red Edge, also known as P. 'tricolor'. It needs free draining soil, likes high humidity, and should be placed near bright daylight to keep its coloration, but not in direct sun. Dry air is its enemy though - mist the plant regularly, especially in winter when the heating is on, but reduce watering slightly in winter. After watering, empty out any outer pot or tray so its not left standing in water. https://garden.org/plants/view/173696/Red-Edge-Peperomia-Peperomia-tricolor/